# IQueryable & ref keyword (adding a where clause)

Tags: c#, parameters, iqueryable, ref

```
IQueryable<SomeType> cases;
```

If I want to add a where clause to the cases query, I have two options, but I don't know which one is better.

It could be either:

```
cases = SomeFunction(cases);
...
private IQueryable<SomeType> SomeFunction(IQueryable<SomeType> cases)
{
  return cases.Where(whatever);
}
```

or

```
SomeFunction(ref cases)
...
private void SomeFunction(ref IQueryable<SomeType> cases)
{
cases = cases.Where(whatever);
}
```

Comment: dont use ref. use first one.

Comment: Also, with first option, you can even chain these calls by making `SomeFunction` as extension method to `IQueryable<SomeType>`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the version without the ref because it gives the caller the flexibility to keep the original query without having to take a copy of their reference before calling your function.

Your caller is likely to want to write code like this:

```
var cases = CreateQueryToFindCases();
var casesFilterdBySomthing = FilterBySomething(cases);
```

Rather than

```
var cases = CreateQueryToFindCases();
var casesFilterdBySomthing = cases;
FilterBySomething(ref casesFilterdBySomthing );
```

They may even want to nest the function calls like this which can't be done so easily with the parameter passed by ref:

```
var casesFilterdBySomthing = FilterBySomething(CreateQueryToFindCases());
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say the first one is better, because it allows "fluent" usage and chaining, for instance:

```
IQueryable<SomeType> cases = ...;
(SomeCondition ? SomeFunction(cases) : cases).Where(...).OrderBy(...) etc.
```